# В папке проекта на Python появилась папка __pycache__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вечер добрый!
Не могу понять откуда в папке с проектом на Python появилась папка `__pycache__`. Что это за папка и как она создалась?

P.s.: Всех с наступившим Новым годом!!!

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869024/5951529

Comment: похожий вопрос http://qaru.site/questions/25404/what-is-pycache

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во время первого импорта модуля, исходный код компилируется в байт-код ([How do I create a .pyc file?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file)). `__pycache__` папка содержит байт-код кэш (в `*.pyc` файлах), чтобы не перекомпилировать каждый раз один и тот же код. Первоначально `__pycache__` папки ввели, чтобы удобней поддерживать несколько версий Питон-интерпретатора ([PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#abstract)).

Comment: Дело в том что я раньше такой папки не видел в моих проектах. Хотя не так много и работаю в Python. Может из-за того что я решил проект модулями сделать ?

Comment: @Rashid-s: когда вы напрямую скрипт запускаете -- он не импортируется  и `.pyc` файл не создаётся (запуск скрипта и `import module` это не одно и то же).

Comment: Тогда почему раньше у меня такая папка не создавалась ?

Comment: @Rashid-s: потому что вы раньше свои модули не импортировали? Или Python 2 использовали? (у вас вопрос имеет метку [tag:python-3.x])

Comment: То есть если я создал файл `main.py` и в нем импортирую другие файлы, которые находятся в этой же директории, то тогда создается такая папка `__pycache__` ?

Comment: где вы импортируете не имеет значения. Если не ясна разница между запуском Питон-файла как скрипта (`python script.py`) и импортированием модуля (`>>> import module`), то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом.